# Flutter & google maps how to save users trajectory

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geolocation, location, maps

I would like to save users' trajectory when they are on a vehicle and save them as a "history of trips" for other calculations Like distance, time, etc..
When I used the directions API, it only gave me the shortest route between the start and the destination, but I need the exact route that the user took
Exactly like Google TimeLine: https://timeline.google.com/maps/timeline

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution since this question was asked ?